# Questions with Infinitive

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, questions

While writing questions with infinitive, I realized that it is common to say

> How to + verb
>
> What to + verb
>
> When to + verb
>
> Where to + verb
>
> Who to + verb

But it is very uncommon to say

> Why to + verb

as confirmed by [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22+why+to+%22%2C+%22+how+to+%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20why%20to%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%22%20how%20to%20%22%3B%2Cc0), for which we prefer the version without "to". I would have thought that all interrogative pronouns should follow the same pattern.

Examples include:

> **Why make** diversity so hard to achieve? [Source](https://hbr.org/2012/06/why-make-diversity-so-hard-to-achieve)
>
> **What to expect** when you're expecting [Source](http://www.whattoexpect.com/)
>
> **How to flatten** your abs with yoga [Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Flatten-Your-Abs-with-Yoga)

**What is the ethymological reason behind this?**

Comment: I doubt if it's an etymological reason, but _why_ is also unusual in that it can't be used as a relative pronoun modifying any other noun than _reason; the reason why_ is grammatical, but not *_the cause/source why_. Of course, _how_ is even more restricted, in that it doesn't ever occur as a relative pronoun at all: _the way to do it_ is OK, but not *_the way how to do it_. _Wh_-questions with infinitives and relative infinitives are intimately related, just like headless relative clauses and embedded question complements are.

Comment: Do you mean embedded questions?

Comment: Could you give an example sentence for at least one of the words? I don't know understand what structure you're asking about.

Comment: @Clare I added a few sentences

Comment: As is hinted by the lack of a question mark, *What to expect when you're expecting* and *How to flatten your abs with yoga* are not questions.